# Keep on fetching from gmail javamail

Tags: api, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

I want to fetch UnRead Emails from Gmail through **JavaMail** + **IMAP/POP3**. i want to fetch mails frequently. i don't want to log in and log out every time. Instead I want to keep myself logged in as long as possible and whenever a new message enters Inbox, i fetch it in that session only rather than logging in again & then fetching it. I am not able to find a way after at the JavaMail API. Can listeners be used? which method can be used to know a new message has arrived Inbox in the running session.

I hope i have described my problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

See the [monitor.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) for the basics.

The server will close the connection if you're not using it actively.  You'll also need a thread that wakes up periodically and pokes the connection, e.g., by calling Folder.getMessageCount().